# Cannot read property $$ of undefined javascript webdriverio

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, webdriver-io

I am trying to access a nested webelement using webdriverio framework.

I have the following code

```
function selectSales(sfilters, salesflowName) {
  const sflow = $$("app-filters-manager app-salesflow-panel mat-expansion-panel").find(element => {
        return element.getText() === salesflowName;
  });

/* The below is to select the checkbox from a list of checkboxes under 
the parent */  
sfilters.forEach(fil => {
    sflow.$$("mat-list-option").find(el => { //* > This is where I am getting error.
        return el.getText().includes(fil);
    }).$('mat-pseudo-checkbox').click();
  });
}
```

I am getting `Cannot read property '$$' of undefined`

Not sure why the error shows up. `'sflow'` is the parent webelement and accessing the child elements using `$$("mat-list-option")` is where the error appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that your selector is not valid. Shouldn't it be like this (selector for looking for class)?

```js
const sflow = $$(".app-filters-manager .app-salesflow-panel .mat-expansion-panel").find(element => {
        return element.getText() === salesflowName;`
```

Same in other selectors. And [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) should return one children, so it is OK.

But if it is valid, are you sure, that elements are in DOM?

Answer (score 1):

Your `sflow` variable is undefined meaning that the following expression does not return anything.

```
$$("app-filters-manager app-salesflow-panel mat-expansion-panel").find(element => {
        return element.getText() === salesflowName;
  });
```

This can happen because of several things:

1. Are you sure the `$$("app-filters-manager app-salesflow-panel mat-expansion-panel")` returns the parent of the element you are looking for? Is the selector correct?
2. Remember that find() goes through and finds **the children** of your  `$$("app-filters-manager app-salesflow-panel mat-expansion-panel")` selector. It may also return multiple children. If that selector is already the element you want to use then remove the following part:

> const sflow = $$("app-filters-manager app-salesflow-panel
>   mat-expansion-panel")<strike>.find(element => {
>           return element.getText() === salesflowName;   })</strike>;

3. Make sure you are passing in the right value for `salesflowName` param
4. `element.getText()` might be returning some text with whitespace in it. Try `element.getText().trim()`

Basically you need to make sure that the value of `sflow` variable gets initialized. Whether its the problem with your selector, `salesflowName` param or whitespace failing the equality test needs to be investigated by debugging.

Good luck!